# How to create a list of random integers in Haskell without any library importing (such as System.random)?

Tags: haskell

There are a couple of good answers to questions similar to mine, but all of them (I tried to go over them as much as I could) use System.random library. What is a good idea to write a code in Haskell to create a list with random integers without such library? I think it is interesting to know what is happening behind the scenes when using System.random.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a random library - if you want to implement your own random algorithm, a) take care that you make sure it is random enough especially when you want to use it for security/cryptography, b) take a look at the existing libraries like mwc-random.

Comment: Where would you want to get your entropy from? In haskell most methods of interacting with the system are provided by libraries, so getting time or reading urandom into a bytestring are both a bit laborious if you don't use the basic libraries.

Comment: That's true. I was curious about the way Haskell handles this problem since I'm quite new to this.

Comment: Which problem is "this problem"? Getting the time? Reading a file as bytes? Extracting a seed from entropic sources? Using a seed to serve numerous requests for random numbers? As it stands your question is too broad for me to want to answer.

Comment: I was referring to my question. I was curious to know what does Haskell do behind the scenes. What if I don't use System.random, what if I want to generate random numbers in a different way. That's all I asked for.

Comment: You can check how `System.Random` works behind the scenes by clicking the `Source` links on [its documentation page](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html).

Comment: very nice, thank you! never thought about that doc page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no source of entropy exposed in the prelude, so the only way you can make random numbers using only the prelude is if randomness comes from somewhere else. You could read your own external source of entropy, or use an existing one like `/dev/urandom`. Opening `/dev/urandom` in binary mode to read it correctly would stray outside of the prelude into `System.IO` (or better `Data.Bytestring`).

Without `System.IO` you can constrain yourself to the portion of the unicode character set that you understand the representation of well. For me that's the lower case letters `'a'` through `'p'` which are `0x61` through `0x70`.

```
randomNibbles :: IO [Int]
randomNibbles = map (`mod` 16) . filter (> 6 * 16) . filter (<= 7*16) . map fromEnum <$> readFile "/dev/urandom"
```

Fundamentally the only way to get entropy from the outside world is with I/O to observe the outside world.

Comment: Very interesting, Thank you.